# Join condition: select only last record by datetime

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have these tables

**Concessions**

Shipment_id, Title, Creation_datetime

```
1, A, 2017-09-13
```

and each concession has more then one SCAN

**SCANS**

```
Shipment_ID, Event_code, TSS_creation_date    
1, 200, 2017-09-10    
1, 400, 2017-09-11    
1, 600, 2017-09-12    
1, 800, 2017-09-15    
1, 900, 2017-09-16
```

In my final result I want

**Result (Concessions)**

```
Shipment_ID,Title, Creation_datetime, LAST_SCAN_AT_CREATION_DATE

1, A, 2017-09-13, 600
```

where I get the `event_code=600` because it's last row with a `creation_date <= concession_creation_date`

I have tried with this query but it is really inefficient and it too much slow that I cannot get result. Do you know how to use a Join?

```
WITH

ShipmentAndScans AS (
    SELECT
        conc.shipment_id,
        (
            SELECT 
                scan.event_code 
            FROM SCANS_TABLE scan 
            WHERE  
                    scan.shipment_id = conc.shipment_id
                AND scan.TSS_CREATION_DATE <= conc.CREATION_DATETIME
               AND ROWNUM <=1 

        ) AS LAST_SCAN_AT_CONCESSION_TIME           
    FROM CONCESSIONS conc        
)  
SELECT *
FROM ShipmentAndScans
WHERE LAST_SCAN_AT_CONCESSION_TIME IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want the following:

```
select sc.*
from (select c.*, s.event_code, s.TSS_CREATION_DATE,
             row_number() over (partition by c.shipment_id order by s.tss_creation_date desc) as seqnum
      from concessions c join
           scan s
           on s.shipment_id = c.shipment_id and
              s.TSS_CREATION_DATE <= c.CREATION_DATETIME
     ) cs
where seqnum = 1;
```

In your version, the CTE is essentially doing a `LEFT JOIN` (via a correlated subquery).  The outer query, though, is turning that logic back into a `JOIN`.

Comment: Seems it works. Do you know how can I get the last record in time (the most recent)?

Answer (score 0):

Do the join, use a row_number()

```
with CTE as
(
select c1.*, s2.*, 
       row_number() over(partition by c1.shipment_id order by TSS_creation_date desc) as rn
from Concessions
inner join SCANS s2
on s2.shipment_id = c1.shipment_id
)
select *
from CTE
where rn = 1
```